# php oci: uncommitted foreign key needed for insert

Tags: php, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

### So my situation is:

### I have 2 tables:

- TABLE_A
- TABLE_B

---

- TABLE_A has an ID as Primary key as an identity
- TABLE_B has an ID as identity and a_ID as Foreign key Referencing the ID from TABLE_A

---

I use oci_execute with OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT so if an insert fails later on, the inserts simply wont happen. And if everyting runs successfully I make a commit at the end;

#### The Problem

I run an insert on TABLE_A that returns the inserted rows ID that I want to use righ after.
But since it hasn't been committed yet I get a foreign key violation error.

#### Possible solution

- I thought of doing a prewritten PL/SQL script but I may run multiple inserts so I would end up string replacing and concatenating multiple inserts strins instead of properly binding variables.
- I even thought of inserting the row anyways and deleting if something fails but that sounds so bad, I'd rather do the string query manipulation.
- Maybe TABLE_A should have a 0 ID that nothing uses and I first use that. Than later on I change it to the inserted one but this sounds horrible as well.

#### Is there any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but - see if my Oracle side of view helps.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> create table table_a (id    number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table table_b (id    number primary key,
  2                        id_fk number references table_a
  3                       );

Table created.

SQL> insert into table_b values (1, 1);
insert into table_b values (1, 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C00105535) violated - parent key not
found
```

Of course it won't work ... there's no parent key in `table_a`.

---

But, if you change foreign key constraint so that it "ignores" whether referenced key exists or not and make it check it at `COMMIT` point, this *might* be what you're looking for.

See lines #3 and #4:

```
SQL> drop table table_b;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table table_b (id    number primary key,
  2                        id_fk number constraint fk_ba references table_a
  3                                       initially deferred deferrable
  4                       );

Table created.

SQL> insert into table_b values (1, 1);

1 row created.
```

See? Insert succeeded, although referenced primary key in `table_a` doesn't exist yet.

So, once you enter it as well ...

```
SQL> insert into table_a values (1);

1 row created.
```

... and commit ...

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

... everything is here:

```
SQL> select * From table_a;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> select * from table_b;

        ID      ID_FK
---------- ----------
         1          1

SQL>
```

---

If the problem is related to PHP, then I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: Oh wow! My teacher didn't mention this about constraints and it is such an easy solution. Thank you!